# How to combine the two same css selector into one?

Tags: html, css

There are two same css selector in the css file.

```
div.left  {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black; }
div.right  {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black; }
```

I find that `div.left div.right` can not combined into one css selector.

```
div.left  div.right{
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black; }
```

How to make the css file simple  in my case?

Comment: `div.left,  div.right` (without the comma it's a parent - child relation). Also note that margin: auto has no effect on a floated element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**

Your first suggestion of

```
div.left  div.right{
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black; 
}
```

actually matches the html code:

```
<div class="left">
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="right>Stuff here</div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

The style will only apply to the `class="right"` div above. This is because a space between selectors in your CSS indicates that it applies only to div elements with a class of `right` which are contained within a parent div of class `left`.

**The solution:**

Instead you want to use a comma to indicate a list of unrelated selectors that share the same style as follows:

```
div.left, div.right{
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black; 
}
```

This now matches the following html code where either div is unrelated to the other and can be placed anywhere in your document:

```
<div class="left">Stuff here</div>
.
.
.
<div class="right">Stuff here</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

just separate the selectors with a comma, like this:

```
div.left,
div.right {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

and now the style will apply for both of the selectors

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comma between them.